# Stack db with mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoose, stack

How do I create a db like a stack? I am currently using mongoose and I want to limit my db with x elements/records. When a new record is inserted, I want to remove last inserted element so it is always x records.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Capped collections**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) are what you're looking for.

Basically, you configure a capped collection like this:

```
db.createCollection( "myCollection", { capped: true, max: 1000, size: 5242880 } )
```